# How to extract text content from all '<t>' tags within paragraph tag using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

```html
<p>
  <pPr>
    <pStyle val="Table"/>
    <rPr>
      <szCs val="20"/>
    <rPr>
  </pPr>
  <r>
    <t>Reproductive toxicity</t>
  </r>
  <r>
    <rPr>
      <szCs val="20"/>
    </rPr>
    <t>/pregnancy</t>
  </r>
</p>
```

I have the following xml code, and I need to parse all such p tags within a table and get the text content within them using XPath in lxml python library. 
I wrote the following XPath, which goes to table->first row->last column->and then the p tag which I have added in html code snippet):

```
'//tbl/tr[1]/tc[last()]/p/r/t/text()'
```

But this will give a list having the two strings in t tags as different list item as :
`['reproductive toxicity', '/pregnancy']`
I need the output as one string as : `['reproductive toxicity/pregnancy']`

Can anyone suggest how to write the XPath for this ?

Comment: Just concat the output? `''.join(list)`?

Comment: This wont work as I need to create a list having contents of all the p tags (there are multiple p tags in a table column), .join() would concatenate all of them.

Comment: Then you must first get all the p tags. Then itrerate though these p tags and search inside each p tag for the t's.

Comment: @Mace can you please tell the XPath for it

Comment: Well I think it would be '//tbl/tr[1]/tc[last()]/p' and then inside the results search for 'r/t/text()'.

Comment: cant there be a single Xpath which does something like itertext() over the p tag descendants ?

Comment: Not sure but I think you could do it with a css selector. One p would result in a child[n] selector for the text. If you remove the child[n] it would be the text for all p's.

Comment: @AayushArora I've given you an XPath 2.0 solution. XPath 2.0 has string-join() which is like your suggested itertext().

Answer (score 3):

This is easy in XPath 2.0+ (which is available to Python users in the Saxon/C product): for example

```
string-join(//tbl/tr[1]/tc[last()]/p//t, '')
```

It can't be done directly in XPath 1.0; you'll have to retrieve the set of `<t>` elements, and then concatenate their values in the host language.

With XPath questions, please always say which version you are using since it often affects the answer.

Comment: Additionally, OP should be made aware that extracting string values that honor OOXML semantics involves handling `w:pPr/w:ind`, `w:r/w:tab`, etc, which will require stepping up from XPath to XSLT or other conversion/transformation language.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged 'lxml' and you indicated there may be multiple `p` tags with similar information, try the following on this modified xml with two `p` tags, and let's see if this is what you are looking for:

```
repro = """
<doc>
  <p>
  <pPr>
    <pStyle val="Table"/>
    <rPr>
      <szCs val="20"/>
    </rPr>    
  </pPr>
  <r>
    <t>Reproductive toxicity</t>
  </r>
  <r>
    <rPr>
      <szCs val="20"/>
    </rPr>
    <t>/pregnancy</t>
  </r>
</p>
    <p>
  <pPr>
    <pStyle val="Table"/>
    <rPr>
      <szCs val="20"/>
    </rPr>    
  </pPr>
  <r>
    <t>Some other toxicity</t>
  </r>
  <r>
    <rPr>
      <szCs val="20"/>
    </rPr>
    <t>/birth</t>
  </r>
</p>
  </doc>
"""
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.fromstring(repro)
targets = doc.xpath('//p')
lsts = []
for target in targets:
    for t in target:
        txt = target.xpath('.//t/text()')
    lsts.append(txt)
for l in lsts:
    print(' '.join(l))
```

Output:

```
Reproductive toxicity /pregnancy
Some other toxicity /birth
```